# How to determine max fd for select?

Tags: c, sockets

Just as straightforward as the title, I want to get the highest fd number to pass into `select` as its first argument yet using `FD_SETSISE` seems to be so inefficient and unnecessary. My assumption is that after my process begins, the latest socket created will always have the highest fd number so I can simply add 1 to it and pass it to `select`, is that true?

Comment: Select should generally be avoided in favour of poll or epoll (linux) or other on windows.  But for learning purposes or simple apps that don't need high performance or deal with lots of connections it's fine to stick with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FD_SETSIZE *is* inefficient.  It is just a convenience macro for the largest number of descriptors allowed in a set.  If you use it, select will search through the entire set even though the highest descriptor you are actually using may be quite low.  That is, if the highest descriptor you want to pass to select is 7 there is no point in iterating from 8 to 1024 (or whatever FD_SETSIZE is equal to on your platform).

> My assumption is that after my process begins, the latest socket created will always have the highest fd number

No, this is wrong.  The OS is going to choose the lowest available file descriptor when it opens a file or socket.  So if in the course of your program if you have 0-7 open, close 5, and then create another socket it will be assigned 5.

The bottom line is that you have to keep track of the highest open socket yourself.  As a practice, since you have to FD_SET the sets you want to use in select before every select call anyway it isn't hard to put a little if statement in there to find the max file descriptor you are adding to the set.  It need not be anything too much involved than something like this:

```
  int maxfd;

  for (i = 0, maxfd = 0; i < nclients; i++)
  {
    FD_SET(clients[i], &read_fds);
    if (clients[i] > maxfd)
        maxfd = clients[i];
  }

  select(maxfd + 1, ........);
```

Alternatives are to look into `poll` and `epoll` which eliminate some of the nuisances of select.