# select() fails when adding m32 flag to Makefile

Tags: c, linux, select, makefile, 32bit-64bit

i have the following code, which simply creates udp socket to listen
to a multicast group.

I'm compiling it using gcc, with -c -g flags, on x64 machine.
When adding -m32 flag to linking & compiling phases in Makefile,
**select()** call is failing with **Invalid Argument**.

After debugging a little bit with and without the flag, i found out that 
using the flag i get all the same values for all variables, except:

**readfds: 0x80.. (repeats 31 times) - WITH -m32 flag**

**readfds: 0x80.. (repeats 15 times) - without the flag**

**sock.sin_zero: 0x5c, 0xD5, 0xff, and some other weird values WITH -m32 flag**

**sock.sin_zero: 0x0,0x0,0x20,0x0,0x0 - without the flag**

*All variables reading is done inside the file loop, right after FD_SET*

I don't really understand why does it changes at whole (as 32 bit program
suppose to run just fine on 64 bit machines) , or why does select() returns
**Invalid Argument** in that case.

could someone please help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/socket.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include "radio_listener.h"

int main_loop(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock_no = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in sock;
    socklen_t sock_size;
    fd_set readfds;

    struct ip_mreq mreq_ip;
    uint16_t mreq_port = 0;

    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
    struct timeval timeout_value;

    if(VALID_ARGC != argc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <mc_address> <udp_port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    mreq_port = atoi(argv[2]);

    /* Initialize a socket */
    sock_no = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sock_no < 0)
    {
        perror("socket() failed!");
        exit(1);
    }
    sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sock.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    sock.sin_port = htons(mreq_port);
    sock_size = sizeof(sock);

    bind(sock_no, (struct sockaddr *)&sock, sizeof(sock));

    /* Initialize the Multicast request */
    mreq_ip.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    mreq_ip.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    

    setsockopt(sock_no, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq_ip, sizeof(mreq_ip));

    while (1)
    {
        timeout_value.tv_sec = TIMEOUT_VAL;
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(sock_no, &readfds);
        int retval = select(sock_no+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout_value);

        if(-1 == retval)
        {
            perror("select() failed!");
            close(sock);
            exit(1);
        }
        if(0 == retval)
        {
            printf("Timeout - Closing socket and exiting\n");
            break;
        }

        if(recvfrom(sock_no, buffer, BUFF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sock, &sock_size) < 0)
        {
            perror("recvfrom() failed!");
            close(sock);
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    close(sock);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc = 0;
    rc = main_loop(argc, argv);

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `select(sock_no+1...` instead of `select(sock_no...`?

Comment: @ryyker
because select goes over the nfds descriptos ( from 0 to nfds -1 ), according to:

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?select

( see lines 5-6 in DESCRIPTION )

Comment: I have always just used the actual value for socket in that argument.  Have not seen the `-1` .  There may be a difference in the windows sockets definition for `select()`  You are on Linux then?  I had not yet noticed.

Comment: @ryyker Yes of course, sorry for not mentioning - i'm in linux dist (kubuntu), on 64 bit architecture

Comment: Windows (winsock) ignores the first argument to select and tests all descriptors in all the fd_sets regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not setting the `tv_usec` field of the timeout argument, so it will contain some garbage (whatever happened to be on the stack where `timeout_value` was allocated).  If that random garbage happens to be a negative number, you'll get the `EINVAL` invalid argument error.  If it happens to be ok, you won't.  Minor changes to things (like using `-m32` or not) will tend to change this.

Comment: OP has not confirmed it yet, but it appears your answer more specifically addresses the issue.

Comment: @chris-dodd 
This is probably it, i'll check it later when arriving home.

One last question - 
If i want timeout value to use only " tv_sec " param, what should i set in "tv_usec" one? will just 0 will cause any other behaviour rather than using "tv_sec" param as the timeout value?

Many thanks

Comment: `tv_usec` should always be in the range 0..999999 -- it's for the fraction of a second part if you don't want a timeout that is exactly an integral number of seconds.  Note that both `tv_sec` and `tv_usec` are integers.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT***
Did you determine the maximum number of fd's?

In general, determine the max number, then pass it to select:

```
  int maxfd;

  for (i = 0, maxfd = 0; i < nclients; i++)
  {
    FD_SET(sock[i], &read_fds);
    if (sock[i] > maxfd)
        maxfd = sock[i];
  }

  select(maxfd + 1, ........);
```

If you have not determined what maxfd is, then it could be problematic.

( From ***[discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22601341/645128)***   )

Comment: That would wait for all sockets up to `sock_no - 1` according to the man pages.

Comment: He's only setting one socket (`sock_no`) in the fd_set, so `sock_no + 1` is clearly correct...